# MediaElement in ListBox causing Memory Leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I have a virtualized ListBox with a lot of GIFs loading from HDD which play in a loop.

I am using Grid as I plan to add more to the control so please stick with it.

LongFileName is a full path.

```
public class cThumbnail3 : System.Windows.Controls.Grid
{
   public string LongFileName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LongFileNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LongFileNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongFileNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LongFileName", typeof(string), typeof(cThumbnail3), new PropertyMetadata(OnLongFileNameChanged));


    static void OnLongFileNameChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        cThumbnail3 t = obj as cThumbnail3;
        t.LoadAsGif();
    }

    private MediaElement ME;
    public void LoadAsGif()
    {
        ME = new MediaElement();
        ME.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"file://" + LongFileName);
        ME.Source = uri;
        ME.MediaEnded += (o, e) =>
            {
                ME.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                ME.Play();
            };
        this.Children.Clear();
        this.Children.Add(ME);
    }
}
```

xaml is simple for now

```
<local:cThumbnail3 LongFileName="{Binding FullPath}" />
```

I am monitoring memory usage as I scroll up and down the listbox. Every time item gets into view it new cThumbnail3 is created and item is playing from the start as it should.

Problem is that after some time Memory consumption gets to 1.2GB and playback stops

**EDIT**
What else I have tried:
Differently adding event + Unload everything when control is out of the view

```
private bool IsVisible { get; set; }

public void LoadAsGif()
{
   ME = new MediaElement();
   ME.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
   Uri uri = new Uri(@"file://" + LongFileName);
   ME.Source = uri;
   ME.MediaEnded += ME_MediaEnded;
}
private void ME_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsVisible) return;
  ME.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
  ME.Play();
}

private PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add
    {
        var wasAttached = propertyChanged != null;
        propertyChanged += value;
        var isAttached = propertyChanged != null;

        if (!wasAttached && isAttached)
            OnPropertyChangedAttached();
    }
    remove
    {
        var wasAttached = propertyChanged != null;
        propertyChanged -= value;
        var isAttached = propertyChanged != null;

        if (wasAttached && !isAttached)
        {
            OnPropertyChangedDetached();
        }
    }
}

void OnPropertyChangedAttached()
{
    IsVisible = true;
    if (ME != null)
        ME.Play();
}

void OnPropertyChangedDetached()
{
    IsVisible = false;
    if (ME != null)
    {
        ME.MediaEnded -= ME_MediaEnded;
        ME.Stop();
        ME.Close();
        ME.Source = null;
        ME = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ME.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual` looks suspicious.  What does the documentation say about it?

Comment: It is required for control, otherwise I get `Additional information: Cannot control media unless LoadedBehavior or UnloadedBehavior is set to Manual.`

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing. I suggest you to put together very simple test project that reproduces the problem you're currently having.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a complete method for the `MediaEnded` event and in the destructor of the class you can write `-=` for the event. I guess the event is the culprit here which may be causing the object to not get disposed properly.

You can also set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"` for the ListBox to improve performance. Look for more about it on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried it, please see edits. IsVirtualizing was already set to True